# Monitorando entradas analógicas Arduíno

Tags: arduino, serial, porta-serial

Estou monitorando mais de uma entrada analógica de um *Arduíno* a todo instante, ou seja, a todo momento estou enviando dados via *serial* para outro software. Qual seria a melhor maneira de enviar esses dados **de modo que eu consiga reconhecer em outro software a qual entrada analógica do *Arduíno* cada dado recebido pertence**?

```
int CANAL1, CANAL2, CANAL3;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);  // configura como entrada
  digitalWrite(A0, LOW);
  pinMode(A1, INPUT);  // configura como entrada
  digitalWrite(A1, LOW);
  pinMode(A2, INPUT);  // configura como entrada
  digitalWrite(A2, LOW);
  analogReference(DEFAULT);
}

void loop() {
    CANAL1 = analogRead(A0);
    Serial.print(CANAL1,DEC);
    Serial.print(" ");
    delay(5);
    CANAL2 = analogRead(A1);
    Serial.print(CANAL2,DEC);
    Serial.print(" ");
    delay(5);
    CANAL3 = analogRead(A2);
    Serial.print(CANAL3,DEC);
    Serial.print(" ");
    delay(5);
}
```

Fazendo dessa maneira os dados chegam na serial em sequência. Exemplo:

> 0 1023 500 1023 400 500 300 200

Assim, se eu perco um dados, qualquer um, eu já perco totalmente a orientação de qual entrada corresponde cada valor.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, Você esta aprendendo a programar.
Você pode criar sua marcação supondo que o software que receberá será seu também. Ou terá que ler a documentação do software que recebe para formatar ao estilo dele.

No caso do software que receberá ser seu mesmo, escreva o que quiser antes de cada dado ADC como por exemplo:

```
Serial.print("A3:");
Serial.print(CANAL3,DEC);
Serial.print(",");
```

E a saída será:

> A3:1024,A2:256,A1:87 ...

Obviamente no cliente dos dados você precisará aprender a tokenizar strings.